FastAPI how to refer to a base/extend jina2 template
In my old flask app i have the following:
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %} 

Im converting my app to FastAPI.
The folders 'static' and 'templates' are subfolders from where main.py resides.
main.py:
app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(GZipMiddleware, minimum_size=500)
app.include_router(default.router)
#app.include_router(data_mgr_view.router)

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
app.mount("/templates", Jinja2Templates(directory="templates"), name="templates")

default.py:
from alpha_insite.config import tmplts

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="",
    #dependencies=[Depends(get_token_header)],
    responses={404: {"description": "resource not found"}},
)

@router.route('/')
async def root(request: Request):
    context = {"title":"test", "content":f"Place for my charts, studies, etc..."}
    return tmplts.TemplateResponse(request=request, name="index.html", context=context)

index.html:
//{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %} 
{% extends "{{ url_for('templates', path='/base.html')}}" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %} 

WHen hitting the root of my url however, i see this:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "templates/index.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "{{ url_for('templates', path='base.html')}}" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 204, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: {{ url_for('templates', path='base.html')}}

I've tried both /templates and /base.html as well.
So im doing something wrong here. what is the proper way of doing this?

You definitely shouldn't be using url_for() for extends. Didn't {% extends "base.html" %} work?

FastAPI is a modern, fast (high-performance), web framework for building APIs with Python based on standard Python type hints. [from official documentation]. Why would anyone use FastAPI to render templates?

I would suggest using the StaticFiles instance for base.html instead, as shown in this anwer and this answer. You might find this answer and this answer helpful as well.

@AKX i was following the documentation here for working with Jinja2:  https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/

@chris those were helpful. i needed to change 'filename' to 'path'
